# sorting three number in a specific order

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

So, I am just trying to sort three numbers in a specific order indicated by user.
[image: Example]

So, in this example, user input three numbers: 1 5 3, and wanna sort them in ABC order which means from minimal to middle to maximum. So, it output 1 3 5.
Second example is sorting in CAB order, which means maximal to minimal to middle.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int i,array[3];
   for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    scanf("%d",&array[i]);
   int max,mid,min;
   max = array[0];
   mid = array[0];
   min = array[0];
   for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
       if(max < array[i])
       max= array[i];
       if(min > array[i])
            min = array[i];
   }
   for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
       if(array[i] != max || array[i]!= min)
         mid = array[i];
  }
   char A,B,C;
   scanf("%c%c%c",&A,&B,&C);

   if(A == 'A')
    printf("%d ",min);

   if(B == 'A')
     printf("%d ",min);
    if(C == 'A')
        printf("%d ",min);
    if(A =='B')
        printf("%d ",mid);
    if(B == 'B')
        printf("%d ",mid);
    if(C =='B')
        printf("%d ",mid);
    if(A == 'C')
        printf("%d ",max);
    if(B == 'C')
        printf("%d ",max);
    if(C == 'C')
        printf("%d ",max);


}
```

Basically, I am just find the max, min and mid in three numbers. Then test the letter A,B or C.

If I input 1 5 3 and ABC(first example), it would print out only 1 3.
For the second example, it only prints out 6 2.

What causes this bug and is there any better way to do this algorithm?

Comment: *What causes this bug* -- Is this a homework assignment?  If so, isn't trying to discover and fix your own bugs part of that assignment?  What debugging have you done?  Did you single-step through your program to see where it goes astray of your plan?

Comment: flush stdout or print a new line after the last `println`.

Comment: Please clarify `"wanna"`?

Comment: *is there any better way to do this algorithm* -- Try and use this method to sort 4, 5, or 20 numbers based on your criteria.  You will quickly see how impractical your method becomes.  So when you say "better algorithm", do you mean in the general case?

Comment: suggest replacing this: `scanf("%c%c%c",&A,&B,&C);` with this: `scanf(" %c %c %c",&A,&B,&C);` (Notice the spaces) so any leading/intervening `white space` is consumed without corrupting the data

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks ( `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` ) via a single blank line.  2) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every (real or optional) opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every (real or optional) closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: always check user input to assure they entered valid data (I.E. `A` `B` and `C`.

Comment: three things, taken in any order (a permutation) is 1*2*3 = 6 possiblities.  So only a max of 6 output statements.  Suggest inputting the values as an array of 3 characters, then use `strcmp()` 5 times to determine which specific order was entered.  Then when the result of the call to `strcmp()` is 0, then print the three values in one call to printf()

Comment: Thank you for helping, I successfully made this work by getting help from you guys ! This is not a homework assignment, just found an algorithm practice website and decided to practice. I have not done any debug yet.  Yes, I was trying to say in general case. How can I sort like 20 numbers by specific order, I see the method I am using is pretty simple and not the best.

Comment: The string compare method is a pretty good one for 3 numbers. What if there is are 10 or 20 numbers need to be sorted. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

First, the `mid` calculation is wrong (logic error), should be:

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    if(array[i] != max && array[i]!= min) // AND not OR
     {
      mid = array[i];
      break; // once found you can break
    }
```

then it's the infamous "scanf eats last linefeed bug", which puts `\n` in `A` because you previously entered the list of the numbers, and shifts the rest of your variables too. You can fix it like this:

```
scanf(" %c%c%c",&A,&B,&C);
```

Comment: I forgot this infamous bug again! Thank you! I made it work by your help!